# Visual studio stack overflow when defining variables (c++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've been trying to solve a competition problem in the style of the link below using c++ (the actual problem that I'm trying to solve isn't available for the public)

http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=aio18int&problemid=1032

I have written a C++ program in Visual studio that attempts to solve it, but when I run this code: (there are some includes for  and  but I couldn't get the formatting).

```
    int main() 
{
int n = 1;

freopen("pairin.txt", "r", stdin);


scanf("%d", &n);

int s[200005];
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &s[i]);
}

int d[100005];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    d[i] = -1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (d[s[i] - 1] == -1) {
        d[i] == s[i];
    }
    else {
        d[i] = i - d[i];
    }
}

int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (d[i] > max) {
        max = d[i];
    }
}

freopen("pairout.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("%d", max);

return 0;
}
```

It returns the error: 
    Unhandled exception at 0x00B11CC9 in a.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow            (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00402000). occurred

Visual studio then opens up a tab of an asm file called chkstk.asm for whatever reason.

I have an idea of when this error occurs normally, but what seemed to be triggering it was defining "int n = 1;" when I stepped through with the  debugger, which absolutely boggles my mind. All I want to do is debug my algorithm, not trying to get int n = 1; to work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, with  the _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS flag enabled.

I tried this in an online IDE (commenting out all the IO lines) and main() returned 0 just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is in `s` and `d` array definitions. These variables are allocated on stack. Occuped space is more than 1Mb, but default stack size in Visual Studio is [1Mb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx):

> **/F** Sets the program stack size in bytes. Without this option the stack size defaults to 1 MB.

So you are run out of stack space.

To fix the problem you should increase [stack size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) or allocate memory on heap or reduce array size (e.g. `int s[100000];` and `int d[50000];`).

Comment: Nice to have an actual classic StackOverflow on the site. Kind of ironic in a way. The domain name should have tipped OP of ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I ruled out this possibility because i swear when I put breakpoints in it would always crash the second it entered main() and I thought it was some kind of crazy bug related to some kind of function call, and I had successfully initialised arrays size 500 000 before, but looking back they were booleans so it made sense it didn't overflow. So glad to get an answer within 30 mins. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheEpicCowOfLife glad to help. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: @Nikita Ohhhhh, so that's what I needed to press. Thanks!